# ctypes - view c_char_p field of returned struct

Tags: python, c, struct, binding, ctypes

I've defined a simple C struct called `TestStruct` and a function `init_struct` to create an instance and return a pointer to it

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    int x;
    int y;
    char* msg;
} TestStruct;

TestStruct* init_struct(int x, int y, char* msg) {
    TestStruct* p;
    TestStruct initial = {x, y, msg};
    p = malloc(sizeof(TestStruct));
    *p = initial;
    return p;
}
```

I compile the C code into a `.so` file using `gcc`. Then, in Python, I want to create a binding using `ctypes` that can access all the members of the C struct

```
import ctypes
import os

class PyStruct(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [('x', ctypes.c_int), 
                ('y', ctypes.c_int),         
                ('msg', ctypes.c_char_p)]

lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(os.path.abspath('/path/to/libstruct.so'))
_init_struct = lib.init_struct
_init_struct.argtypes = [ctypes.c_int, ctypes.c_int, ctypes.c_char_p]
_init_struct.restype = ctypes.POINTER(PyStruct)

myStruct = _init_struct(1, 4, ctypes.c_char_p(b'hello world'))
print(myStruct.contents.x, myStruct.contents.y, myStruct.contents.msg)
```

The integer members of the struct (`x` and `y`) print out fine, but I can't figure out how to print the string that `msg` points to. Instead of the expected `hello world`, I end up seeing a bytes string `b'\x01`. My hunch from other reading is that I'm truncating the true, longer string and only showing the first byte.

Comment: Maybe you need convert from bytestream to string?

Comment: FYI, you can pass `b'hello world'` directly without the `ctypes.c_char_p(b'hello world')` wrapping.

Comment: regarding: `p = malloc(sizeof(TestStruct));
    *p = initial;` 1) should always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure to `mallloc` was successful.  2) the second statement will not copy the contents of `initial.  Suggest using: `strncpy( p, &initial, sizeof( TestStruct ) );`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing `ctypes.c_char_p(b'hello world')` to `init_struct` and copying the pointer to the `c_char_p` block in the assignments to `initial` and `p`. However, that pointer to the `c_char_p` block is **only valid for the duration of the call to `init_struct`**, i.e., once `init_struct` returns, that `c_char_p` pointer will no longer be valid and accessing it will be undefined behavior. In other words, the copy of that pointer you took in `myStruct.msg` is dangling and should never be accessed outside `init_struct`.

Remember that `ctypes` does *NOT* violate Python's Garbage Collection (GC) rules. In this line `myStruct = _init_struct(1, 4, ctypes.c_char_p(b'hello world'))` `ctypes` will allocate some `c_char_p` object, copy in the string b`hello world`, null terminate it, and pass the raw pointer to that memory to the C side. Then the C side runs and your code takes a copy of that pointer. When the C side returns, `ctypes` releases its reference to the `c_char_p` object. Python's GC then finds that the `c_char_p` is no longer referenced and so it gets garbage collected. Hence, you end up with a dangling pointer in `myStruct.msg`.

The proper solution is to clone `msg` *contents* inside `init_struct` and provide a `fini_struct` function to free that clone memory when you are done with it, something like:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    int x;
    int y;
    char* msg;
} TestStruct;

TestStruct* init_struct(int x, int y, char* msg) {
    TestStruct* p = malloc(sizeof(TestStruct));
    p->x = x;
    p->y = y;
    p->msg = strdup(msg);
    return p;
}

void fini_struct(TestStruct* p) {
    free(p->msg);
    free(p);
}
```

Then the python side:

```
import ctypes
import os

class PyStruct(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [('x', ctypes.c_int), 
                ('y', ctypes.c_int),         
                ('msg', ctypes.c_char_p)]

lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(os.path.abspath('/path/to/libstruct.so'))
_init_struct = lib.init_struct
_init_struct.argtypes = [ctypes.c_int, ctypes.c_int, ctypes.c_char_p]
_init_struct.restype = ctypes.POINTER(PyStruct)

_fini_struct = lib.fini_struct
_fini_struct.argtypes = [ctypes.POINTER(PyStruct)]

myStruct = _init_struct(1, 4, ctypes.c_char_p(b'hello world'))
print(myStruct.contents.x, myStruct.contents.y, myStruct.contents.msg)

# when you are done with myStruct
_fini_struct(myStruct)
```